# Could installing Dreamweaver affect how your browser runs scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I just posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164275/using-javascript-with-html-to-get-a-selected-option-and-display-a-string-based-o) a few hours ago and got helpful responses, both codes displayed the output the way I needed, but after editing my code (even tried copy-pasting the working code into Dreamweaver) I couldn't replicate the successful result on my laptop.

So I thought of putting it up on JSFiddle, and since my desktop PC was already logged into my email, I made the JSFiddle account on there and ran the code successfully, now I try running the same fiddle [(link)](https://jsfiddle.net/Blitzilla/8a91hfj5/2/) on my laptop and it won't display the output (just like Dreamweaver wouldn't). The only difference (software-wise) between the two computers is that the laptop has Dreamweaver 2015 installed and the desktop doesn't.

I'm stumped, have any of you run into a similar issue before? is there something I'm missing? all suggestions appreciated.

for reference (and since I apparently can't link to JSFiddle without posting code), here's the code I'm trying to get to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.clear();

function showDetails(event) {
  console.log(event);
  var x = event.srcElement;
  var val = x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;

  var t = event.srcElement.selectedOptions[0].text;
  document.getElementById("Details").value = t;
}
var el = document.getElementById("slctOrder");

el.addEventListener("change", showDetails, false);
</script>


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <title> Hot Buns </title>
 </head>


<div>
  <h2> Welcome to Hot Buns </h2>
  <h3> Ham can we bee'f service? </h3>
</div>
<div>
  <h2> Place an order </h2>
</div>
<form method="get" id="frmOder">
  <select id="slctOrder">
    <option hidden selected="selected" value="0"> please select one of today's specials </option>
    <option value="1"> Last of the Mo-jicama </option>
    <option value="2"> Cheesus Is Born Burger </option>
    <option value="3"> Beets of Burden Burger </option>
    <option value="4"> Paranormal Pepper Jack-tivity Burger </option>
  </select>

  <output id="Details" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dreamweaver :/ 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a [known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839278/python-built-in-server-not-loading-css) [issue](https://github.com/SickRage/old-sickrage-issues/issues/742#issuecomment-178986350) that happens on certain installs of Dreamweaver.

Dreamweaver changes things in the registry that have certain effects on loading CSS, etc. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839278/python-built-in-server-not-loading-css) answer should help you fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I only found one of the reg keys that answer refers to (only text/css, no application/css in my reg), renamed as suggested and restarted the machine but the output still won't display at all, neither on DW nor JSFiddle. is there an environment you would recommend I use for HTML/JS other than DW? I know notepad works but I'd appreciate something more interactive and beginner-friendly.

Comment: I'd highly suggest Atom(by Github) or Brackets.